# Working through the XML Dom?

Tags: php, xml, dom, tree

I am new to the xml dom and I am trying to to retrieve the value in the '' tags. 
The problem is I am not sure how to work down to that level in the dom. 
I have tried to do something like this:

```
itemXML.getElementById("gender").getElementsByTagName("item").nodeValue;
```

But that returns 'undefined', how would I specify which  tag I want to retrieve the value of?

Below is the contents of my xml document:

```
  <dataFields>
    <items id="gender">
          <item>Male</item>
      <item>Female</item>
    </items>
<items id="age">
    <item>0-3 years</item>
    <item>3-6 years</item>
    <item>7-16 years</item> 
    <item>17-25 years</item>
    <item>26-40 years</item>
    <item>41-65 years</item> 
    <item>65+ years</item>
</items>
```

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($itemXML);

$genderItems = $xpath->query('/dataFields/items[@id="gender"]/item');

foreach ($genderItems as $genderItem) {

    echo $genderItem->nodeValue . "\n"; // "Male", "Female"

}
```

Comment: Ummm this is a million times better than what I was trying to do. I just implemented it and it does exactly what I needed, but in like a hundred less lines of code than what I was going to use. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute in XML without a namespace prefix is just a normal attribute, only in html it is the identifier. So in xml documents, the attribute name would have to be "xml:id" to be found by `getElementById()`. The `getElementsByTagName()` method returns a list of element nodes, not just one. You will have to use `foreach()` or the `item()` method to access the elements in the list.

But here is an easier way. `DOMXpath:evaluate()` allows you to use xpath expression to fetch nodes and values from a DOM.

Here is some demo source:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<dataFields>
  <items id="gender" xml:id="xml_gender">
    <item>Male</item>
    <item>Female</item>
  </items> 
  <items id="age">
    <item>0-3 years</item>
    <item>3-6 years</item>
    <item>7-16 years</item> 
    <item>17-25 years</item>
    <item>26-40 years</item>
    <item>41-65 years</item> 
    <item>65+ years</item>
  </items>
</dataFields>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);

// difference between id and xml:id
var_dump(
  $dom->getElementById('gender'),
  get_class($dom->getElementById('xml_gender'))
);
/* Output:
NULL
string(10) "DOMElement"
*/

// getElementsByTagName returns a node list
var_dump(
  get_class($dom->getElementById('xml_gender')->getElementsByTagName('item'))
);
/* Output:
NULL
string(11) "DOMNodeList"
*/

// you can iterate node lists
foreach ($dom->getElementById('xml_gender')->getElementsByTagName('item') as $item) {
  var_dump($item->nodeValue);
}
/* Output:
string(4) "Male"
string(6) "Female"
*/

// it is easier with xpath
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//items[@id = "gender"]/item') as $item) {
  var_dump($item->nodeValue);
}
/* Output:
string(4) "Male"
string(6) "Female"
*/

// DOMXpath::evaluate() can be used to fetch values directly, too.
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//items[@id = "gender"]/item[2])')
);
/* Output:
string(6) "Female"
*/
```